# How to redirect user back to the same table location?

Tags: html

I have a dynamically table that it is incremented every time a new product is added to the database.

Each row of this table contains the name of the product, categories etc etc, you get the idea, it also contains a column with a link to another page, this link is only clicked if user wants to edit a specific product. Once user clicks on the link and makes the changes to the product they get redirect back to the product table page. That is working fine until you have 1000s products and you want to update row 570 and 571, now it becomes a bit annoying as once they get redirect back to the product table from editing row 570, the user gets redirect as any other page to the top, I would like to redirect the user back to the row 570 so that they dont have to scroll all the way down to 571 again.

Hope you guys understand what I am trying to say. I have tried using anchors in the past, but failed to get it working, I wish I had the code still but I have deleted since was no good, but users are now complaining about this so i need to fix it now.

Im not looking for you guys to post a code, I just want some advice on what i need to do, does anchors work with tables row's location? as i tried them in the past and it didnt work, could have just been bad coding. What would you guys advice me to do?

```
$product_list .= "<tr><th>$prod_cat</th><th>$sub_cat</th><th>$prod_name</th><th>$price</th><th>$q_left</th>
                  <th> $id1 </th><th> £$package </th><th><a href='dragNdrop.php?pID=$id'>Add more images</a>
                  &nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href='editProduct.php?pID=$id'>Edit</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
                 <a href='index.php?delID=$id&prodName=$prod_name'>Delete</a></th></tr>";

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Category</th>
    <th>Sub-Cat</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $product_list; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure anchors work with table rows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use anchor points. Give each row an ID (e.g. S-Number, ID-Number, Name etc). You can then jump to that anchor point via a link on redirect e.g. test.com#article570. I hope this helps

```html
<a href="#570">goto 570</a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>test1</th>
    <th>test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="570">
    <td>Article 570</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried somethign similar like this in the past. I will give it ago again, maybe i just developed a bad code in the past, will update you once im done. Thank

Comment: It did work i must had done something wrong last time i tried this. thanks

Comment: Nah it didnt work again, redirecting anchors through links seems to now work. That was the problem i had last time. I cant seem to find a way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = $(window);
var row = $('#tableid').find('tr').eq( line );

if (row.length){
    w.scrollTop( row.offset().top - (w.height()/2) );
}
```

Or Try this

```
var w = $(window);
var row = $('#tableid').find('tr').eq( line );

if (row.length){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: row.offset().top - (w.height()/2)}, 1000 );
}
```